# What other objects are accessible inside <%# %> tags in aspx?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I run into similar codes like this all the time in aspx pages:

```
<asp:CheckBox Runat="server" ID="myid" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column").Equals(1) %>'>
```

I was wondering what other objects I have access to inside of that <%# %> tag. How come DataBinder.Eval() and Container.DataItem are not visible anywhere inside .CS code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within <%# %> tags you have access to

1. Anything that is visible in your code-behind class (including protected methods and properties).
2. Anything declared on the aspx page using <@import @>.
3. Anything passed in as the event arguments when the ItemDataBound event is fired (e.g. RepeaterItemEventArgs, DataListItemEventArgs, etc).

*Container* is actually a wrapper for RepeaterItemEventArgs.Item, DataListItemEventArgs.Item, etc. So you can actually access it in code behind within your ItemDataBound events as *e.Item* (e normally being the event arguments parameter name).

*DataBinder* is also accessible in code behind by using *System.Web.UI.DataBinder*.

On a side note, casting the Container.DataItem is preferred over using Eval. Eval uses reflection so there's an overhead there. In VB.NET it would be something like

```
<%#DirectCast(Container.DataItem, DataRow)("some_column")%>
```

Or C#

```
<%#((DataRow)Container.DataItem)["some_column"].ToString()%>
```

Comment: `<%#DirectCast(Container.DataItem, DataRow)("some_column")%>` should be `<%#DirectCast(Container.DataItem, Data.DataRow)("some_column")%>` if you haven't imported the `Data` assembly in your .aspx/.ascx file

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have access to anything within scope of the page class, though the results of the expression are converted to a string, so you can't embed conditional expressions the way you can with "<%" expression holes.

[Here](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/278.aspx) is a nice blog post which dives under the covers of the generated ASPX class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

<%# is specific to inline ASPX databinding like the link ckramer posted suggests.

> How come DataBinder.Eval() and Container.DataItem are not visible anywhere inside .CS code?

To access the binding item in codebehind you would need to set up an [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET generates a subclass of [TemplateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.aspx) for each occurence of a template. Databinding statements are expressions used in a method inside that class. Thus, you can call any public/protected instance method on TemplateControl. See [any example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510015225/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092706-1.aspx) that uses XPath, as those will use the XPath and XPathSelect methods; Eval, XPath and XPathSelect are all instance methods on TemplateControl.

[DataBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.aspx) is actually a separate class, and Eval is a public static method on it; it's in  System.Web.UI. DataBinder.Eval and plain Eval are not directly related though they do very similar things visibly.

I believe that "Container" is actually a local variable or parameter where databinding statements are compiled. I can't remember its type at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Great example

```
<%#((System.Data.DataRow)Container.DataItem)["ColumnName"].ToString()%>
```

Answer (score 1):

using `<%# %>` actually means that code inside this block will execute when `page.DataBind()` method is being executed. Thus you can access anything at that point accessible as protected/public to that particular page/control.